# How to change controller position to bit down in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to change controller position to bit down in Google Maps ?

[image]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlPositioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hidden [custom control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls) at the [control-position](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlPositioning) `TOP_LEFT` and give it a height equal to the height of the overlay(let's assume 120px);

The zoom-and pan-control place at LEFT_TOP:

```
panControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
},
zoomControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
}
```

The `LEFT_TOP`-controls will be drawn beyond the `TOP_LEFT`-controls, as result the pan- and zoom-control will be placed 120px(approximate) beyond the top of the map.

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/95Wjz/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/95Wjz/)